# swf Flash sits over top of my menus

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, flash

I have a swf file that my graphics designer has created for me that is placed on my intro page of my asp.net mvc website. The problem is that when the site is viewed with Internet Explorer (works as it should in firefox) the flash image sits over the top of my dropdown sub menu's (menu's at top of page that when user hovers mouse over they expand a sub menu).

Following is the markup for the flash image:

```
<embed name="presentation" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src='<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Media/PictureHeader.swf") %>' bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="best" 
             allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" scale="noscale" flashvars="autostart=true" 
             pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
            width="560" height="192">
```

Any ideas on what i need to do to get it so that it is always sent to back?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting `wmode="transparent"`?